# Referencing several models from one model class- Bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, model, refactoring

I want to obtain all notifications for current user with this code:

```
current_user.follows.each do |follow|
    follow.followable.open_notifications.each do |notification|
        if !notification.reads.include?(current_user)
            @open_notifications += notification 
        end
    end
end
```

So far I had this code in my controller however I know this kind of logic should be place in model class. 
After moving code:

**OpenNotification Controller:**

```
OpenNotification.fetch_unread(current_user)
```

**OpenNotification Model:**

```
def self.fetch_unread(user)
    @open_notifications = []
    user.follows.each do |follow|
        follow.followable.open_notifications.each do |notification|
            if !notification.reads.include?(user)
                @open_notifications += notification 
            end
        end
    end
    @open_notifications
end
```

**EDIT:**

Classes involved:

- User
- Follow - who(user) follows what(followable)
- Followable(polymorphic - may be User, Event or a Place)
- OpenNotification - stores information about the change of followable object
- Read - who read which notification (user_id and open_notification_id)

**User:**

```
has_many :follows, class_name: 'Follow',
                 source: :user

has_many :follows_as_fallowable, 
                class_name: 'Follow',
                as: :followable

has_many :followers, through: :follows_as_fallowable,
                   source: :user
```

**Event:**

```
has_many :follows, as: :followable
has_many :followers, through: :follows,
                         source: :user

has_many :open_notifications, as: :followable
```

**OpenNotification:**

```
belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
has_many :reads
```

**Reads:**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :open_notification
```

---

My question is if it is a good practice to refer to multiple classes from the class responsible for one particular resource?
If this is not a good practice, how the code should be refactored?

Comment: I am not concerned about the use of different classes (It looks to my like there are only two classes involved: `User` and some kind of `Follower`). But your nested `each` loops will result in bad performance, because it fires to many queries to the database (N+1 problem). I would focus to optimized that. Without knowledge of your database schema and model associations it is hard to give advise. Can you please post how the classes are connected?

Comment: Relations are pretty complex, i have added the info(see edit) and brief explenation.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing several models from within one model is perfectly fine as long as you can justifiably say that your Notification model should be aware of the User model (basically do a majority of notification interactions deal with users as well?).  In the little that you show here I would say it does however you'll have to consider this question application wide and re-evaluate it.  If you think that that may be a bit of a stretch I would recommend ecapsulating this logic into a separate class to keep your code more maintainable and predictable if someone were to ever collaborate with you on this (think Service Object).  Also, where you're appending notifications to @open_notifications you should consider using `<<` since that won't reconstruct the @open_notifications object every time whereas `+=` will instantiate it over and over again leaving more work for the garbage collector.  On large operations you'll see a massive speed gain here.